# 而且每一颗导弹的事实上整个境内- What does this mean?

Tags: translation, meaning

I'm kinda confused as to what this means, I've tried to do a translation, from my understanding and the translation, does this means that "in fact, each missile can cover the entire country", if not could someone correct my understanding.

The entire context: 而且每一颗导弹的事实上整个境内，所有的军事基地，都有着导弹防御系统，都有导弹发射基地，这些导弹能够覆盖国家任何一处地方。 I understand everything else apart form the first part.

Comment: Need to ask the author to improve his Chinese.

Comment: " 而且每一颗导弹的事实上整个境内" this sentence are wrong and imcomplete,becauseit doen't have a verb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"事实上整个境内，所有的军事基地，都有着导弹防御系统，都有导弹发射基地，这些导弹能够覆盖国家任何一处地方" is a complete paragraph

而且每一颗导弹的 is an incomplete sentence. It might be a copy and paste error, totally out of place at the beginning of this paragraph.

Another clue is 而且 (also) is rarely used to start a paragraph. It strongly suggests a sentence is before it

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The first part is incomplete. A good guess of the missing word(s) is by looking at the last part: "这些导弹能够**覆盖**国家任何一处地方", which seems to echo the first. After adding the missing words, it reads: "而且每一颗导弹的事实上**覆盖**整个境内", which then makes some sense.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!